# Better way to use json mixin with spring 4 controller

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Is there a better way (possibly using annotations) to add a mixin to a spring controller.

Currently I am doing this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        params = "q")
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public final String getAccountsViaQuery(@RequestParam("q") final String query) 
        throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    final List<Account> matchingAccounts = accountService.findByAccountNameOrNumber(query);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SerializationConfig serializationConfig = mapper.getSerializationConfig();
    serializationConfig.addMixInAnnotations(Account.class, Account.SearchJsonMixin.class);

    return mapper.writeValueAsString(matchingAccounts);
}
```

I would rather do this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        params = "q")
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public final List<Account> getAccountsViaQuery(@RequestParam("q") final String query) 
        throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    return accountService.findByAccountNameOrNumber(query);
}
```

Looks much better to me, no boilerplate code and the return type is compiler checked.

Is is possible to use some sort of annotation on my controller to add a json mixin?

Comment: Are you configuring your app with XML or Java config?

Comment: @Sotirios The Spring configuration is in XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote an annotation to solve this issue.

https://github.com/jackmatt2/JsonResponse